# Pandas: find maximum value of column for specific id and date only

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new column and assign a value "x" based on maximum value of column "Difference" with respect specific combination of contract number and ref_date:

Dataframe:

[image]

When contract code is '1' and ref_date = 28-02-2021, then max of of column 'difference' is taken and assign a value 'x' (sort of flag) against difference = 3, since maximum value is 3 for that particular Contract and Ref_Date.

I tried:

[image]

but in this way, all other rows are disappearing. I want all the rows to be there e.g row with contract=1 and ref_date = 29-02-2021 and Difference = -2

Comment: This way I am not able to create a new column and assign value = 'x'  to the row which has Difference = 3, contract = 1 and Ref_date = 28-02-2021

Comment: try : `df_1.groupby(['Contract','Ref_Date'])['Difference'].transform('max')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of what you want is that you want to create a new column with a mark 'x' side by side with the column 'Difference' for those rows with max values of 'Difference' with their corresponding groups.   For this, you can use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create the new column by:

```
df_1['max_entry'] = np.where(df_1['Difference'] == df_1.groupby(['Contract','Ref_Date'])['Difference'].transform('max'), 'x', ' ')
```

---

```
#Assuming df_1 has the following data before new codes:

print(df_1)

    Contract    Ref_Date Last_update  flag  Difference
0          1  2020-12-31  2020-12-27     0          -4
1          1  2021-01-31  2021-02-02     0           2
10         1  2021-02-28  2021-02-26     0          -2
3          1  2021-02-28  2021-03-03     0           3

# Run new codes:
df_1['max_entry'] = np.where(df_1['Difference'] == df_1.groupby(['Contract','Ref_Date'])['Difference'].transform('max'), 'x', ' ') 



print(df_1)

    Contract    Ref_Date Last_update  flag  Difference max_entry
0          1  2020-12-31  2020-12-27     0          -4         x
1          1  2021-01-31  2021-02-02     0           2         x
10         1  2021-02-28  2021-02-26     0          -2          
3          1  2021-02-28  2021-03-03     0           3         x
```

Here, [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) acts like an if-then-else statement to test if the condition in its first parameter is true.  If yes, it will assign value in the second parameter (i.e. 'x') for the rows in the new column.  Otherewise, it will assign value in the third parameter (i.e. ' ') for the rows in the new column.

The condition we test in the first parameter is whether a value in the column 'Difference' is equal to the max. in its corresponding group.  The max value is found by `df_1.groupby(['Contract','Ref_Date'])['Difference'].transform('max')` which uses [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) instead of `.agg()` so that the result has the same size as your original 'Difference' column, without cutting out non max. values.  By this, as you pointed out, can then still keep all entries.

### Edit

A more concise way of coding is as follows:

```
df_1['max_entry'] = df_1.groupby(['Contract','Ref_Date'])['Difference'].transform(lambda x: np.where(x == x.max(), 'x', ' '))
```

Here, we put the `np.where()` call inside the [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) call. Gut feeling is that this version of coding might be more efficient and execute faster since it does not need to repeatedly calculate the group max once for each row.  Instead, it calculates the group max only once for each group.

However, with a time profiling with %%timeit for this version and the initial version of codes, we get contrary results:

```
%%timeit
df_1['max_entry'] = df_1.groupby(['Contract','Ref_Date'])['Difference'].transform(lambda x: np.where(x == x.max(), 'x', ' '))

2.65 ms ± 46.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
df_1['max_entry'] = np.where(df_1['Difference'] == df_1.groupby(['Contract','Ref_Date'])['Difference'].transform('max'), 'x', ' ') 

1.92 ms ± 55.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The initial version is about 38% faster.  The reason for this unexpectedly result is because the initial version has the `max()` function using the Pandas built-in function which has been optimized for fast ndarray() operation.  However, the new concise version is using a custom lambda function which has not been optimized for system performance.

Hence, this concise version has the cost of slower execution.  You can use this concise if your dataset is small.  For big dataset, the initial version, though a bit more clumsy, is the recommended version.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thanks alot

Comment: @aarijkhatib  Added a concise but slower version of codes.  You can take a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its way faster.